# Saving Workbook as a CSV with User Prompted File Path

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen many questions of a similar nature, but I am experiencing a specific issue. Here is the code I am using:

```
filePath = GetFolderName
NewBook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Summary Book", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Above, `GetFolderName` is a function, defined below:

```
Public Funtion GetFolderName(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim lCount As Long

GetFolderName = vbNullString

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Show
    For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
    Next lCount
End With
End Function
```

This functionality was not written by me, but rather by a coworker so I don't totally understand it's inner workings. When I run the code, it works fine, but whatever folder I select, it saves the file one folder previous.. I.E.- if I click through 3 folders and save, it saves the file in the 2nd folder. Also I noticed previously that it is saving it as a "File".. one that will open with an application such as Notepad, as opposed to a .CSV that you open with excel. Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` is prompting for a *folder*, not a *file*.

Comment: Maybe I am confused as to what it's supposed to be doing. I am selecting a folder to save it to. Is that what I want to do? @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the filepath but then don't use it when you save the file

```
filePath = GetFolderName
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:= Filepath & "\Summary Book.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, and when I implemented it, it worked perfectly thank you. But I have one final question. When it saves, it doesn't save as  CSV, it saves as a "File" that you have to use notepad or another generic application to open. can you think of any reason that would be happening?

Comment: It's probably that your system has notepad set as the default program for opening the filetype ".CSV". If you right click on the file with the shift held down you can use "Open With..." to change the default program

Comment: I tried that but the "Open With..." doesn't offer that option. On the object properties it lists its File Type as a "File Folder".. so I don't think the code is actually saving it as a CSV, which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I had someone else answer the question. I was missing including ".csv" at the end of the title and I was confusing the code. Thanks for your help!